# convert to numeric string with double quotes in R

Tags: r, quotes

I have a dataframe that contains some fields with double quotes or single quotes, for example:

```
""spendtime""   ""Average %""   ""Physical Memory """
""3600""    ""0.00518809""  17.17660342"
""3600""    ""0.00000000""  19.18255917"
```

So, I tried to use `as.numeric` conversion, but the fields look like truncated

```
as.numeric(filter$spendtime)
[1] 30 30
```

do you have any idea how to remove the quotes or to convert properly?

Comment: Try `as.numeric(gsub('"', '', filter$spendtime))`

Comment: great answer!  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to remove the `"` and then apply `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(gsub('"', '', filter$spendtime))
```